# I want to list all my users from the database, I am getting a strange error - undefined method `each'. What should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, foreach

This is the code for listing my user

```
<div>

  <% @govornik.each do |g| %>

     <p><%= g.name %></p>
     <p><%= g.description %></p>

   <% end %>

</div>
```

this is the code from the controller

```
class GovorniciController < ApplicationController
     def new
     end

     def show
       @govornik = Govornik.new
     end

end
```

Govornik is my model.
here is the code of my model and the migration of that model

```
class Govornik < ApplicationRecord

end
```

migration code

```
class CreateGovorniks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :govorniks do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

conclusion of the problem:

I want to display all my users from the database table Govornici which is connected to the model govornik and I am getting the following error

[image: image off the error page]

Comment: gdje zapinje Nikola? hehe look this answer below just put this line into controller def show @ govorniks = Govornik.all end and in view use @ govorniks.each

Answer (score 0):

Why is that a "strange error"? It is a totally expected error. This:

```
@govornik = Govornik.new
```

creates a new `Govornik` record. And, a new `Govornik` record doesn't include the method `each`. So, the error is exactly what you would expect.

If you want a collection of all your `Govornik` record, then you should create a variable more like:

```
@govorniks = Govornik.all
```

In which case the variable `@govorniks` (which will be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`) will have the `each` method which you can use to iterate over all the records.

BTW, I suggest that you copy errors from your console and include them as text in your question. Screen shots are difficult to read on some devices. And, it makes it impossible to copy and paste in case we need to do that to help you with your problem. Also, screen shot errors don't show the whole stack trace which can sometimes be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @jvillian is correct.

```
def index
 @govorniks = Govornik.all
end
```

Next time, you could use a scaffold. Much easier to create controllers, models, and views when you're getting started. You can learn to reverse engineer code from the output.

```
rails g scaffold Govornik name:string description:string
```